# Can't write metadata when input contains container

Tags: ffmpeg

I don't understand this.

For the first command the metadata (handler, language) is stored correctly.
The second keeps the metadata from temp.mkv.

What am I doing wrong?

Works:

```
ffmpeg^
 -i video.h264 -i audio1.dts -i audio2.dts -i sbtl1.srt -i sbtl2.srt^
 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -map 4:0^
 -metadata:s:v:0 handler="AVC"^
 -metadata:s:a:0 language=deu -metadata:s:a:0 handler="DTS-HD Master Audio"^
 -metadata:s:a:1 language=kor -metadata:s:a:1 handler="DTS-HD Master Audio"^
 -metadata:s:s:0 language=ger -metadata:s:s:0 handler="Deutsch (forced)"^
 -metadata:s:s:1 language=ger -metadata:s:s:1 handler="Deutsch"^
 -movflags disable_chpl^
 -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a alac -sample_fmt:a s16p^
 output.m4v
```

Don't:

```
ffmpeg^
 -i temp.mkv -i sbtl1.srt -i sbtl2.srt^
 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 1:0 -map 2:0^
 -metadata:s:v:0 handler="AVC"^
 -metadata:s:a:0 language=deu -metadata:s:a:0 handler="DTS-HD Master Audio"^
 -metadata:s:a:1 language=kor -metadata:s:a:1 handler="DTS-HD Master Audio"^
 -metadata:s:s:0 language=ger -metadata:s:s:0 handler="Deutsch (forced)"^
 -metadata:s:s:1 language=ger -metadata:s:s:1 handler="Deutsch"^
 -movflags disable_chpl^
 -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a alac -sample_fmt:a s16p^
 output.m4v
```

temp.mkv = video.h264 & audio1.dts & audio2.dts

Comment: Show the complete log from the second command.

Comment: Here you go https://pastebin.com/mYHKpiuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ffmpeg 4.0.3 it is handler since 4.1 (maybe earlier) it is handler_name.